# Parameter Dereferencing in solr json facet

Tags: solr, faceted-search, solr6

I am using solr6.6. I am trying to use parameter Dereferencing for json facets.

There can be multiple prices for all the documents(assume `sp, price1, price2, price3, price4` are the prices for all the documents).

Based on the query, I have to fetch the **minimum value among the combination of those prices** and create facets among them.

It can be done with frange. But is there a way that this can be done with json facets?

Below sample query works:

`localhost:8983/solrcloud/myconf/select?q=apple&
json.facet={
    'prices':{
    'type': 'query',
    'q': "${FIELD}:[0 TO 20]"
    }
}
&FIELD=sp`

But when I try to use something like this:

`localhost:8983/solrcloud/myconf/select?q=apple&
json.facet={
    'prices':{
    'type': 'query',
    'q': "${FIELD}:[0 TO 20]"
    }
}&FIELD=min(price1, price2, price3, sp)`

My other query can be like as below:

`localhost:8983/solrcloud/myconf/select?q=apple&
json.facet={
    'prices':{
    'type': 'query',
    'q': "${FIELD}:[0 TO 20]"
    }
}&FIELD=min(price1, price3, sp)`

or

`localhost:8983/solrcloud/myconf/select?q=apple&
json.facet={
    'prices':{
    'type': 'query',
    'q': "${FIELD}:[0 TO 20]"
    }
}&FIELD=min(price1, price2)`

I can use any kind combination like (price1, price2) or (price4, sp).. etc

I am getting below error:

```
<lst name="error">
<lst name="metadata">
<str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str>
<str name="root-error-class">org.apache.solr.parser.ParseException</str>
</lst>
<str name="msg">
org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'min(price1, price2, price3):[0 TO 20]': Encountered " ":" ": "" at line 1, column 12. Was expecting one of: <EOF> <AND> ... <OR> ... <NOT> ... "+" ... "-" ... <BAREOPER> ... "(" ... "*" ... "^" ... <QUOTED> ... <TERM> ... <PREFIXTERM> ... <WILDTERM> ... <REGEXPTERM> ... "[" ... "{" ... <LPARAMS> ... "filter(" ... <NUMBER> ...
</str>
<int name="code">400</int>
</lst>
```

Is it possible to do function query while forming query?

Comment: This isn't actually about dereferencing (which seems to work), but how to create a function query that evaluates to "fetch documents where the minimum value between these two fields are between 0 and 20", right? The most efficient way to solve that is by simply index a `actual_price` field which is set to the minimum value when indexed - it'll be usable across all functions, no special syntax or function queries and `frange` localparams necessary .. and it'll perform as fast as possible.

Comment: Thanks, @MatsLindh for the suggestion. I think I haven't framed my query properly. Can you please check my updated query and please let me know if you have any suggestions